# Generating dynamic color map in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to generate a rather automated system to define colours in SASS. I have a list of colours, defined with a hexidecimal value (like so: `$color--deep-ocean: #123143;`) and a global `$colors: ();` definition.

I then want to create their RGBA values dynamically, and given variable interpolation isn't an option in SASS, I've tried my hands at maps.

The idea is to feed a `set-color` function a name and a color to populate my `$colors` variable with `map-merge`, which I can then retrieve with `get-color`. Here below are my two function definitions and how I'm *trying* to use them:

```
@function color-set($name, $hex) {
    $submap: (hex: $hex);

    @for $o from 0 to 20 { // Going in increments of 5
        $percentage-decimal: $o*0.05;
        $percentage: $o*5;
        $submap: map-merge($submap, ($percentage: rgba($hex, $percentage-decimal)));
    }

    $colors: map-merge($colors, ($name: $submap));
    /* We should then have a map that looks like this:
    $colors: (colorname: (
    hex: #000000,
    0: rgba(0,0,0,0),
    5: rgba(0,0,0,.05),
    // and so on…
    100: rgba(0,0,0,1)
    )
    )
    … right? */
}

@function color-get($name, $opacity: hex) {
    @if $opacity != hex { // Returns RGBA value
        @return map-get(map-get($colors,$name), $opacity);
    }
    @else { // Returns hexidecimal value
        @return map-get(map-get($colors,$name), hex);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if my functions are confusing! I'll try to comment them better.

This is how I'm trying to define a colour (part of `_variables.scss`):

```
color-set(bkgrnd, $color--deep-ocean);
```

And here's how I'm trying to use my colours:

```
body { // These colours have been defined, too …supposedly
    background-color: color-get(bkgrnd, 80);
    color: color-get(white);
}
```

Here is the error I get on _variables.scss:

**Invalid CSS after "...ackground color": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "color-set(bkgrnd, $"**

So I feel like I'm missing something. I've had my head wrapped around this for four hours and I'm going mad. It's probably super simple stuff but I can't seem to figure it out. I use SASS casually, so I might not be aware of some syntax issue but if anyone has a clue about how to fix this, I'd be quite grateful.

Have a nice day and thank you for taking the time to read my post!

Regards,
Chris

PS: I compile this in Brackets with the Brackets SASS plugin, if ever that information is relevant.

Comment: I've working with something similar, check it out and let me know if it works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWZdZK

Comment: @kurenn While your code doesn't work the same way as mine, it did help me figure a few things out to solve my issue, so thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I could imagine that, but as long a helps you a bit....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging some more, I found out what my issue was. SASS functions must have a `@return` directive in order to work. As a result, I updated my `color-set` function, and added `@return $colors;` at the end of it. Then, I just needed to give some directive so the function wouldn't be called "out of the blue", so I assigned my `$colors` variable to it like such:

```
$colors: color-set(bkgrnd, $color--deep-ocean);
```

I think it might be a bit repetitive to reassign `$colors` to itself all the time, but given this only affects performance during compilation, and not on my final CSS file, I can get away with it. There might be a better way (and I'm all ears if you have an idea!) but for now this fits my needs just fine.

And like that, I am able to handle my colors using maps. Thanks to anyone who had a look at my problem, and sorry for posting this - I should have taken some time to cool down and think some more. I hope this helps someone else who is stumbling on the same problem to fix their issues!

Take care,

Chris

PS: If ever you wanted it, below is the full code.

**_colors.scss**

```
$color--deep-ocean: #123143;
$color--yellow: #ffce00;
// And so on, and so forth…
```

**_mixins.scss**

```
@function color-set($name, $hexval) {
    @return map-merge($colors, ($name: $hexval));
}

@function color-get($name, $opacity: hex) {
    @if $opacity != hex { // Returns RGBA value
        $opacity-decimal: $opacity/100;
        @return rgba(map-get($colors,$name), $opacity-decimal);
    }
    @else { // Returns hexidecimal value
        @return map-get($colors, $name);
    }
}
```

**_variables.scss**

```
$colors: color-set(bkgrnd, $color--deep-ocean);
$colors: color-set(main, $color--yellow);
// And so on, and so forth again…
```

**Usage example:**

```
body {
    background-color: color-get(bkgrnd); // Returns #123143
    color: color-get(main); // Returns #ffce00
}

button {
    border: 2px solid color-get(main, 50); // Returns rgba(255, 206, 0, 0.5)
}
```